# Turning off webcam in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, webcam

I'm running this example code which simply shows my webcam image on screen

```
    CvCapture* capture = 0;
    Mat frame, frameCopy, image;

    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY ); 
    if( !capture )
    {
        cout << "No camera detected" << endl;
    }

    cvNamedWindow( "result", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    if( capture )
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            IplImage* iplImg = cvQueryFrame( capture );
            frame = iplImg;

            if( frame.empty() )
                break;
            if( iplImg->origin == IPL_ORIGIN_TL )
                frame.copyTo( frameCopy );
            else
                flip( frame, frameCopy, 0 );

            cvShowImage( "result", iplImg );

            if( waitKey( 10 ) >= 0 )
                break;
        }
        cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
        waitKey(0);
    }
}
```

When I run it on Windows the camera turns off after executing the function cvReleaseCapture as expected, instead when using the same code in Ubuntu the camera stays on while the program is being executed (the LED indicator is on and other programs cannot use the device).

No error messages are shown, what could be the problem here?

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.7 and my webcam is a Logitech c170

Comment: did you debug through? what were the warnings?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that i get the following message when executing `cvCaptureFromCAM`: `HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_S_CROP` the debugger does not show me any additional warnings.

Comment: did you build opencv WITH_V4L=ON ? did you install one of the gui dependencies? did you install these (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.7/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation) dependencies? try updating gtk. try re-installing with qt support (WITH_QT=ON)

Comment: to be clear: v4l (video4linux) is the library to convert various camera device outputs to rgb values. i.e. it works as a codec. opencv then uses these values. qt OR gtk is needed to open up/close gui specific data. a highgui error may be related with any of these.

Comment: Tried all of that, the only change is that now with Qt the window has zoom and move options but the webcam behavior is the same. Thanks for your advice, i'll keep checking that